# How to ensure supply voltage is not killed going into IC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, battery-charging

I'm working on a school project in a team where I'm in charge of the Power Management Unit to charge a small battery.

Although my part of project will take rectified DC from my team member (who's working on the rectification CRT), there's no guarantee that it will be a "clean" DC.

To charge the battery ([GMB051215](https://www.powerstream.com/lip/GMB051215.pdf)), I'm planning to use the [MCP73831](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf). Based on the MCP73831's datasheet, it should operate fine with a supply VDD within a range of 3.75V to 6V and a tiny supply current in the microamp range.

My partner says his design for the rectification CRT can supply 6V. Presumably, I would want that supply going into this IC to not have too many ripple so I'm thinking a voltage regular should take care of that.

I got a warning from my professor that whatever I do, I need to ensure that voltage going into my IC is not killed so that the whole thing does in fact work and I'm mainly considering the voltage regulator option right now for that reason. What could happen if I didn't use a regulator, what could happen if I did?

We're still in the design phase of things so I couldn't say what my partner's output actually looks like or anything like that.

Comment: Also, thanks for all the edits. Definitely should have been more careful writing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there's no guarantee that it will be a "clean" DC.

In a work situation, when different people are tasked with different modules of a design, you would expect that the level of quality of the DC is known.  So, basically, there *would* be a guarantee, or at least a firm understanding, of what's coming out of that section of the overall circuit.

The downside of this in a student project is that you don't necessarily know what's practical until you've given it a try.

> What would happen if I didn't use a regulator?

It depends on how the rectification stage is designed.  A plain old diode bridge and capacitor stage will have a peak voltage that depends on the AC line, and a ripple that depends on the capacitor used.  If you were designing a piece of consumer equipment, you'd want to know if you could use that and nothing more, so you'd look at whether you can find a combination that -- for expected AC line voltages -- never exceeds the voltage that'll break your chip, and never dips down far enough that your chip will stop working.

You have a pretty tight supply voltage range, so this may not be possible.

Note that if that stage is done with an off-line switching supply, then its output will be regulated, so you *would* have a guaranteed output voltage range.

> what could happen if I did?

Basically, extra expense and complication, you'd need to choose your regulator carefully, and anything easy will suffer an efficiency hit.

Easiest would be to use something like a LM7805 regulator -- but if you use that specific part, read the datasheet *carefully*, particularly the part about "dropout voltage".  The short story is that those old first-generation three-terminal regulators need about one and a half or two more volts on the input than they deliver on the output -- so if you use that part, then the *troughs* of your ripple need to be at around 6.5 to 7V.

The second easiest would be to find a truly low dropout regulator (LDO).  Be careful -- for a while distributors were calling *every* three-terminal regulator a "low dropout" regulator.  You want to look for a regulator that drops half a volt or less.  With a good LDO your power rectifier student can hand you less voltage, and your circuit will still work.  Choose carefully, and pay attention to getting the capacitors on the input and output right -- these vary by regulator, so you need to read the data sheet and do what it says.

The third easiest -- but cheapest -- would be to follow the circuit given in Figure 6.1 in the datasheet.  They call out a zener diode across the input leads to the chip, to limit the voltage.  **This can cause problems** -- it will only work if there's something to limit the current to the zener.  In the days of old cheap unregulated wall-warts, you could count on the wall-wart transformer having enough leakage so that the voltage would drop with rising current.  Using nice parts in the AC to DC converter actually causes problems -- in that case you may need to use a series resistor to limit current to the zener.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed reply